# MySQL 8: Granting column level permissions?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-8.0

I hope you can help me with my problem / question.
I can´t give column level permissions to a SQL view. I have found several ways to do it on the internet but none of them work properly.

The sentence is as follows:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [db].[table] (column) TO [user]
```

I am wondering, if I have a SQL view with three columns, can I make a user only be able to see two columns of that same view?

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right sintax is:

```
GRANT SELECT (col1, col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Or if you want to include other accesses try:

```
GRANT SELECT (col1), INSERT (col1, col2) ON mydb.mytbl TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

Check doc for more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges

Comment: Thanks bro!!I had already tried it that way but it gave me an error, but now I have managed to make it work. I must have been wrong before :S